# Ember {{#with ... controller=...}} gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookupFactory' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to access properties of a controller (actually a mixin extended by a controller) in Ember, and I need to use the {{#with}} handlebars helper.  I get the error:

*Cannot read property 'lookupFactory' of undefined*

The place I'm trying to specify the controller for each looks like this:

```
{{#with orders.order controller='ordersIndex'}}
```

I have also tried just about every combination I can think of:

```
{{#with orders.order controller='orders'}}
{{#with orders.order controller='Orders'}}

Tried specifying the controller for the route that seems to work:
{{#with orders.order controller='brokerageAccount'}}
{{#with orders.order controller='BrokerageAccount'}}
{{#with orders.order controller='Brokerage'}}
```

No luck with any of them.

**All Code is in JSBin:**
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cabak/1/edit?html,js

Output view of the two routes:

Broken one: (here if you open the console, you'll see the error)
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cabak/1#/orders

This one works: you'll see some data.
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cabak/1#/orders/tradier/12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a bug with the `{{with}}` helper, because if you use the `{{#each elem in model}}` and update the {{with}} to use the `elem` variable: `{{#with elem.orders.order controller='ordersIndex'}}` all works.

This is the updated `orders/index` template:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="orders/index">
  <div class="inline-headers">
    <h4><label>Brokerage: </label>{{titleize brokerage}}</h4>        
  </div>
  {{#each elem in model}}
    <h4 class="account-header"><label>Account: </label>{{account_number}}</h4>
    {{#with elem.orders.order controller='ordersIndex'}}
      {{partial "_orders_table"}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

And this is the updated jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/piwuyare/1#/orders

Comment: The bug notwithstanding, is it a better pratice, in general, to use #each x in y instead of just #each?  I can see how it would be more explicit and readable.

Comment: I think both are ok, but I personally like the explicit version too. I created a PR [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4774) fixing your problem